# Is this attempt at a more python style decorator in c++ reliable / safe

Tags: c++

Coming to c++ from python, this is as close as I can get to a python like decorator.

This solution feels a bit like a hack because the code to be run after the function to be decorated, in the Timer destructor is call implicitly. It does work though.

My question is:
Is this safe and reliable, or more specifically is the destructor of the Timer class guaranteed to be called directly after the function returns (the Timer instance going out of scope).

```
class Timer{
    time_t time;
    std::string name;
public:
    Timer(std::string name): name(name)
    {
        time = now();
    }
    ~Timer()
    {
        printf("time taken by \"%s\" was: %d\n", name.c_str(), (now() - time));
    }
};


void my_function(){
    Timer _(__func__);
    // function code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First answer your question, yes it's safe.

---

I just write this, I think this more like python decorator (like you can change parameter).

*Not well tested, just demonstrate the idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

template<typename T>
auto TimeIt(T callable){
    return [=](auto&&... args){
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        callable(args...);
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end-start;
        std::cout << diff.count() << "s\n";
    };
}

void my_function(){
    // function code
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(0.5s);
}

auto my_function_2 = TimeIt(my_function); //you cannot reuse the name, though

int main(){
    my_function_2();
}
```

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zrYkUzDH6MBBFwmi)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that is a safe, reliable and conventional way to do this.

It kind of *is* a bit of a hack, because destructors are designed to do cleanup tasks rather than produce key output, but it's a hack that everybody uses and is happy with.

Well done!